# Identity involving Sum of Inverse of Product of Integer partitions

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions

Is there a way to prove the following identity

\begin{equation}
\sum_{l = 1}^{k} \left( \frac{(-s)^l}{l!} \sum_{n_1 + n_2 + \ldots n_l = k} \frac{1}{n_1n_2 \ldots n_k} \right)= (-1)^k  {s \choose k} \, , 
\end{equation}
where $k$ and $n_i$'s are positive integer and $s$ is a real number. I have checked this identity on Mathematica for several $k$'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the equality $(1-x)^s=\exp(s\log(1-x))$. Since
$$\exp(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\quad\text{and}\quad\log(1-x)=-\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{x^m}{m},$$

we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\exp(s\log(1-x))&=\exp\left(-s\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{x^m}{m}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\left(-s\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{x^m}{m}\right)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-s)^n}{n!}\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{x^m}{m}\right)^n.
\end{aligned}$$

Thus the coefficient of $x^k(k>0)$ of $\exp(s\log(1-x))$ is
$$\sum_{l = 1}^{k} \left( \frac{(-s)^l}{l!} \sum_{n_1 + n_2 + \cdots +n_l = k} \frac{1}{n_1n_2 \ldots n_k} \right).$$

On the other side, the coefficient of $x^k$ of $(1-x)^s$ is $(-1)^k  {s \choose k}$. Now we get the desired result.